# How insert edge on graph without source and target? JS

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I want to add solely the line on the graph.How insert edge on graph without source and target?Or tell me how using JS, add a line to the graph

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the example app grapheditor. The shape palette in the toolbar has a number of lines that you can drop on the graph without any targets.